# How to dynamically split result into nested table

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Hi I'm having trouble trying to split my db object result into the correct table for display.

Basically I'm trying to acheive this

```
<div class="panel"> $row->skill_group
   <table class="collapse">
     <thead> 
       <tr>
        <th>$row->name</th>
       </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
       <tr>
          <td>$row->skill_name</td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
          <td> $row->competency_name </td>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

There can be many unique skill_groups and many skill_names but each person and their competency should only be displayed once for each skill.

My mysql returns the correct data however I can't figure out how to loop over the result so that I can split it in between the table that is nested from the div container.

For example the mysql result would be

```
======================================================================
| skill_group_name     | skill_name  | competency_name    | name
======================================================================
| PHP Frameworks       | Codeigniter | Working Knowledge  | User name1
| PHP Frameworks       | CakePHP     | No Knowledge       | User name1
| Database             | T-SQL       | Working Knowledge  | User name2
======================================================================
```

and I need to fit it into the html structure above.

The result I'm after is

```
======================================================================
 PHP Frameworks 
======================================================================
| Codeigniter | Working Knowledge  | User name1
| CakePHP     | No Knowledge       | User name1
======================================================================
 Database 
======================================================================
| T-SQL       | Working Knowledge  | User name2
======================================================================
```

I have managed to get the grouping of the skill_group sorted with:

```
if($row->skill_group_name != $skill_group_name)
{

    echo '<div class="panel-heading"><a href="#" data-target=".skill'.++$counter.'" data-toggle="collapse">' . $row->skill_group_name;
    $skill_group_name = $row->skill_group_name;
    echo '</a></div>';
}
```

But I'm missing how to write the loops for the data table itself, how do I do this?

Comment: have you tried foreach? like foreach($result as $row){ echo $row->name ; etc etc }

Comment: @cartalot yes, my code is contained in a foreach($skills as $row) however when I come to split the skill_group (with the if statement) I don't know how to keep the <div> container open, so I can then loop over the $skill_names etc

Comment: You don't need to do that. First do a loop as you have done, but don't echo. Rather, save each into it's own section array. then at the end, implode each section. You will save yourself a headache

Comment: @Rasclatt - got an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I commented, I think you should save to an array, then `implode()` the sections:

```
//Just some fake data
$array[]    =   array('PHP Frameworks','Codeigniter','Working Knowledge','User name1');
$array[]    =   array('PHP Frameworks','CakePHP','No Knowledge','User name1');
$array[]    =   array('Database','T-SQL','Working Knowledge','User name2');

// Loop through the data
foreach($array as $row) {
    // Save the table column html to array
    $section[$row[0]][] =   '<tr><td>'.$row[1].'</td><td>'.$row[2].'</td><td>'.$row[3].'</td></tr>';
}
// Loop through the section array you made
foreach($section as $title => $all) {
    // Wrap it
    echo '<div>'.$title;
    // Implode
    echo '<table>'.implode(PHP_EOL,$all).'</table>';
    echo '</div>';
}
```

Comment: This is close to what I wanted thanks. How do I arrange the array to get the skill_name to display once, and every user name should be in a new column of the table. I'm thinking I need to arrange the array into multi-dimensional a bit more?

Comment: Oh so a user might have `Codeigniter` twice?

Comment: multiple users can have same skill yes, but a user will only have say for example "codeigniter" once (with their relevant competency).

Comment: Oh so you want to break out each user with their skills but also break out by skill_group_name?

Comment: Yes that is right. Sorry, I didn't explain that well. So your group is e.g. "PHP Frameworks" under that you can have many "skills" e.g. "codeigniter" and each user is then under that skill with their competencies.

Comment: Yeah, then probably the easiest would be to make a sub array as you say.  Maybe `$section[$row[0]][$row[3]][]`.